# can anyone tell me why my model shows up like this

Tags: rendering

i have recently started on blender.  i been working on model for a while and i came to this problem. when i render image it doesnt either show the model or show up weird. i have been trying to find what the problem is. can anyone tell me what the problem is?   heres the image[image] ?

Comment: Have you severly altered your color management? Does this issue continue to occur, when you append your objects into a new scene?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and modify the text to add more information. We can't guess what you are trying to do, or what the model is supposed to look like, or how you set up your project or your textures,  compositing nodes or render settings.